# How to import a large wikipedia sql file into a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wikipedia

I need a database table with "topics" so I downloaded wikipedia's sql file of categories (enwiki-latest-category.sql.gz on http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/)

The file is 74MB (unzipped) but the mysql limit is 32MB. How can I import this file?

By the way: I tried bigdump (http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) but it also seems to have an import limit of 32MB.

Comment: I would open the file in a text editor and delete a bunch of it. Problem solved in about 15 seconds.

Comment: Can't you change the limit? I'm sure there is a option for it somewhere in the MySQL configuration.

Comment: how are you trying to import file? Are you trying to import a local mysql?

Comment: I'm trying to import the SQL-file into my existing database by creating a new table.

Comment: chris, editing the file in a text editor is a nightmare, as it is just too big!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You could split it in pieces of 32MB and import them individually. It shouldn't be too time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mysql installed on your Windows desktop, I have something crazy you may want to try.

Please perform the following steps on your local mysql box

- STEP 01) Unzip the file enwiki-latest-category.sql.gz to enwiki-latest-category.sql
- STEP 02) `CREATE DATABASE mycat;`
- STEP 03) `mysql -u... -p... -Dmycat < enwiki-latest-category.sql
- STEP 04) Export the CREATE TABLE for category

  mysqldump -u... -p... --no-data mycat category > category_00.sql
- STEP 05) Dump the data divided into 10 sections. Since the AUTO_INCREMENT is 134526529, round it to 135000000 (135 million). Dump 20% (27 million) at a time

Just run 5 mysqldumps using the `--where` option against `cat_id`

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info mycat category --where="cat_id <=  27000000"                         | gzip > category_01.sql.gz
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info mycat category --where="cat_id  >  27000000 AND cat_id <=  54000000" | gzip > category_02.sql.gz
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info mycat category --where="cat_id  >  54000000 AND cat_id <=  81000000" | gzip > category_03.sql.gz
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info mycat category --where="cat_id  >  81000000 AND cat_id <= 108000000" | gzip > category_04.sql.gz
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info mycat category --where="cat_id  > 108000000"                         | gzip > category_05.sql.gz
```

Upload these 6 files, unzip them,  and load them in order.

Give it a Try !!!